# In the category $\mathsf{Set}$ regular epis are stable under pullback

Tags: category-theory

I read that in the category of sets regular epis are stable under pullback. I know that epis in $\mathsf{Set}$ are surjective maps, but I don't see why the pullback of a regular epi should be surjective. My thought is that $f'g' = fg$ need not be surjective, so also $g'$ and $f'$ need not be surjective.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{g}>> B\\
@V{f'}VV @V{f}VV \\
C @>{g'}>> D
\end{CD}$$

Comment: In fact, regular epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Set}$ = surjective maps. If you work concretely you will immediately see that the pullback of a surjective map is a surjective map.